Is using khaluq on oneself haram or halal?
The following shows two seemingly  contradictory ahadith on applying khaluq.

It was narrated that Zaid bin Aslam said: "I saw Ibn 'Umar dyeing his beard yellow with Khaluq and I said: 'O Abu 'Abdur-Rahman, are you dyeing your beard yellow with Khaluq?' He said: 'I saw the Messenger of Allah [SAW] dyeing his beard yellow with it, and there was no other kind of dye that was dearer to him than this. He used to dye all of his clothes with it, even his 'Imamah (turban).'"
Sunan an-Nasa'i 5085


Narrated Ammar ibn Yasir:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The angels do not come near three: the dead body of the unbeliever, one who smears himself with khaluq, and the one who is sexually defiled except that he performs ablution.
Sunan Abi Dawud 4180

Is one of them inauthentic? Or could this be an instance of abrogation?

Necessary detail and reference about the question should be present in the post. People are not going to follow a link just to understand the question.

There is a difference between:

using it to dye hair
using it to dye clothes
using it as a body paint for skin (like women use henna to decorate their hands) or using it as a perfume

It is the third one which is makruh to a greater degree and this is what is meant in the second hadith.

عن عمار بن ياسر، قال قدمت على أهلي ليلا وقد تشققت يداى فخلقوني بزعفران فغدوت على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فسلمت عليه فلم يرد على ولم يرحب بي فقال ‏ اذهب فاغسل هذا عنك ‏ ‏.‏ فذهبت فغسلته ثم جئت وقد بقي على منه ردع فسلمت فلم يرد على ولم يرحب بي وقال  اذهب فاغسل هذا عنك ‏.‏ فذهبت فغسلته ثم جئت فسلمت عليه فرد على ورحب بي وقال ‏ إن الملائكة لا تحضر جنازة الكافر بخير ولا المتضمخ بالزعفران ولا الجنب ‏‏.‏ قال ورخص للجنب إذا نام أو أكل أو شرب أن يتوضأ
Narrated Ammar ibn Yasir:
I came to my family at night (after a journey) with my hands chapped and they perfumed me with saffron. In the morning I went to the Prophet (ﷺ) and gave him a greeting, but he did not respond to me nor did he welcome me.
He said: Go away and wash this off yourself. I then went away and washed it off me. I came to him but there remained a spot of it on me. I give him a greeting, but he did not respond to me nor did he welcome me.
He said: Go away and wash it off yourself. I then went away and washed it off me. I then came and gave him a greeting.
He responded to me and welcomed me, saying: The angels do not attend the funeral of an unbeliever bringing good to it, nor a man who smears himself with saffron, nor a man who is sexually defiled. He said: He permitted the man who was sexually defiled to perform ablution when he slept, ate or drank.
— Abu Dawud


نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن يزعفر الرجل جلده
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) forbade men to use saffron on their skin.
— Nasai

